# Cant add a delegate to a subview

Tags: objective-c

I am having some main viewController , that i want to add a subview to it, as a child, which is also a viewController  .

My approach is that when you finish editing that subview, he will tell the main view to do something with a delegate.

1. does this approach to create many subviews as `viewcontrollers` that being added to the main view, and notify him with delegate when something happens , is a good approach ?
2. why can't i add a delegate listener to my subview ? i created the protocol in my subview, and the main view is adding a subview and needs to subscribe to its delegate , so :

> ```
> UIViewController *search = [[SearchView alloc]init]; //my subview that post delegate
>     //[search delete:self]; //can't add delegate here,
>     [self addChildViewController:search];
>     // search.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 550);
>      [self.view addSubview:search.view];
>     [search didMoveToParentViewController:self];
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no delegate property in UIViewController but you call

```
[search delete:self];
```

On this object, not on SearchView object. If you added delegate property on SearchView you need to change the declaration to:

```
SearchView *search = [[SearchView alloc]init];
```

The other thing is if you added delegate in SearchView.h file like:

@property(assign) YOURDEL delegate;
you should call:

```
[search setDelete:self];
```

instead of:

```
[search delete:self];
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! it worked, i have changed it to be searchView and it worked as expected . Does this approach is right ? to add many view controllers as subviews, to some main view, and they all will post delegates to him, to notify him when to remove them/do something else ?

Comment: I prefer to use UIView instead of UIViewController because it's a smaller object. But it all depends on your needs. If your subview don't do too much you can you your root view controller to manage all uiview subviews and you don't need to even use delegate but if there is a lot going on in the subview logic you can stick with UIviewCOntroller.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SearchView *search = [[SearchView alloc]init]; //my subview that post delegate
[search setDelegate:self]; // or search.delegate = self;
```

Also you need to create protocol and its required methods for your action in your subview. don't forget to add the delegate in main view interface.

Hope this may fix your issue